# Specifying different "sp" font size if the app is rendered for tablet or phone for android

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to render different textSize for a phone and a tablet? Let's say I want to use "14sp" if it is a phone and "18sp" if it is a tablet.

Tablet has little more real estate so it would be better if we can increase the font size a bit to make it more legible.

Should we use styles and have two styles folder like styles/ and styles-sw600dp/ and specify font sizes there? What is the best way to do it system wide instead of having to specify the style in every element?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/design/style/devices-displays.html at the bottom of this page ...

Comment: @user1797612 I do not see anything in the link provided regarding textSize.

Comment: you are supposed to read everything because everything is related, in a nutshell always use the sp unit http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html

Comment: @user1797612 I think you did not read the question. I'm talking about sp. But I want to use different sp sizes for different screens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify dimensions for this not styles.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <dimen name="my_font_size">14sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

in values/dimensions.xml and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <dimen name="my_font_size">18sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

in values-large/dimensions.xml or values-sw600dp/dimensions.xml  I generally put tablet stuff in values-large because there are still a significant amount of Gingerbread tablets in use.  Then, you can reference it wherever with:

```
android:textSize="@dimen/my_font_size"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems to be the way to go. We can reference the dimensions in styles if we want to and have a single style for both.